# Modify user and system variables in Visual Studio 2017 installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, installation

I want to **append** the installation folder of my program as value to the path variable of user and system variables.

I followed michaelmoo's instruction.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21390793/9678802

The problem is that the existing value of path variable will be removed.

Comment: Did you wipe out your Path trying this? [There are some tricks you can use to try to restore your Path variable](https://superuser.com/q/523688/11906). Not options to toy with, but last resorts.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul No, I had a backup. I am using the free version of Advanced Installer now.

Comment: OK, but you can verify that the path was indeed wiped out? I am asking because certain OS registry keys are under protection and / or auto-recovery. I do not think this is the case for the Path (yet).

Comment: Using [TARGETDIR]appname.exe as path value replaced the path value and using [~][TARGETDIR]appname.exe as path value replaced path in registry with a REG_MULTI_SZ file and [TARGETDIR]appname.exe as value.

Comment: Obviously please make sure that package never gets used - compulsive warning :-). I wish system restore would preserve the Path specifically, so it could be easily restored in several generations. Advanced Installer is a very nice product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Digression***: Adding to the Path involves some **security risks**, some **performance issues**, and can cause **application interference** - and probably a few other things. It is best avoided in general. It is a "*known risk*" avoided by deployment professionals - if they can help it.

> [**The concept of AppPaths**](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/08/how-the-app-paths-registry-key-makes-windows-both-faster-and-safer/) is a (partial) alternative to
>   updating the Path environment variable. It allows your application to
>   be started from the **`Start => Run`** dialog, but it does not work
>   from the command line.

[Seems to not work from command prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822749/129130).

---

***Warning***: [Ouch, that answer is very bad indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21390793/9678802) (with apologies to the author who clearly tried to help others). That procedure should not be followed in any shape or form though! It is so dangerous that I have seen people sent out the door for far less. **`Wiping out a whole developer teams' environment path with a package deployment will cause drama - that you can be sure of`**. The warning really needs to be that strong in this case. I have seen it happen, and even by packages made by experienced professionals.

***Built-In Support***: As far as I am concerned, [the correct answer from the above "thread" is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560425/129130). Windows Installer has built-in support for adding environment variable that takes care of all **merging** and **update issues** - and it even has **rollback support** - meaning your environment variable will be restored to its original state should the package installation fail. *`This built-in feature is a "must use" functionality`*.

---

***Deployment Tool***: So the built-in feature has to be used, but how when the tool does not support it? The best option is to get a ["real deployment tool"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130), especially since [there are several further problems with the Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) (**Note**: this is not pitching products, it is telling people about serious pitfalls that will cause real problems in almost all cases - what product you choose is up to you - obviously - but the VS Installer Project just isn't a complete solution).

***WiX***: [Updating the Path variable using WiX is simple enough](https://github.com/robmen/gitsetup/blob/49583db00bc9e22ab3f0c0cb49b59b48fcbf6a10/src/Package/GitProduct.wxs#L15). And the documentation for the [Environment element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html).

***Orca***: Though it is possible to "post-process" your compiled MSI and create the required entry in the [Environment table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/environment-table), I would recommend that you use a proper tool instead that has been tested and designed to help you succeed in general. A comma wrong or a star wrong in the Environment table and you get completely wrong behavior.