# Is there a way to specify command line aliases within a Wix project?

Tags: cmd, wix, wix3, wix3.10

I want to deploy my app with an wix based installer and also want it to be available in the Command line, so that I can call my app after installation just like this:

```
C:\> myApp "Some parameters"
```

I know that I can achive this by adding my installation directory to PATH, but I need a bit more.

I would like to call my app by another name, for example my app is named like

```
MyApp.Cli.exe
```

and for a few reasons I would like to keep that naming scheme in the install folder. But on the command line I would like to call my App like

```
C:\> MyApp
```

instead of

```
C:\> MyApp.Cli.exe
```

Any ideas how to achive this? Thank you a lot for any help.

Comment: Type `doskey /?`.

Comment: Yeah, I know doskey, but I want to set the alias during installation via Wix

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/addconsolealias

Comment: Added a note on WiX and the WIX special-purpose environment variable. Maybe have a quick look.

Answer (score 1):

***App Paths***: I suppose you can try **`App Paths`**? It is an alternative to updating the **`PATH variable`**. I don't think it works via the command line, but it works in the Windows Shell - or in other words when you do <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type in **`"YourAppName"`** (without the quotes), then you run the right application without updating the systems **`PATH`** variable.

> ***Reminder***: Remember to test on all OS versions you intend to support!

Note on WiX:

> ***Sidenote***: [The WiX toolkit](http://wixtoolset.org/) does something interesting. It adds its own environment variable **`WIX`** and sets it to the path of the
>   toolkit's installation folder. Hence you can do this in scripts and
>   the **`cmd.exe`** window: **`"%WIX%bin\candle.exe"`** in order to launch the binary in question (**`candle.exe`**, **`light.exe`**, **`etc...`**).

***App Paths, Registry***: In the registry your **`App Path`** would look something like this:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe]
"(Standard)\Your Path Here\Your Path Here\MyApplicationFullName.exe"
```

Actual reg-file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\DaTool.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files\\My Tools\\DaFullNameOfDaTool.exe"
```

---

***WiX Markup***: Running **`heat.exe reg MyRegExport.reg -out MyWiXFile.wxs -sfrag -suid`** to convert the exported **`*.reg`** file to WiX markup yields something like this (not tested, please adjust as appropriate - just a generalized idea of how to do this):

```
<Component>
  <RegistryKey Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\DaTool.exe" Root="HKLM">
    <RegistryValue Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]DaFullNameOfDaTool.exe" Type="string" />
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

---

***Command Line***: It seems it works to use the "start" command from a command line window:

```
start datool
```

But it does not work to just go **`datool`**. Didn't test much, have a play with it?

---

***Links***:

- [**How the App Paths Registry Key Makes Windows Both Faster and Safer**](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/08/how-the-app-paths-registry-key-makes-windows-both-faster-and-safer/) (Helge Klein)
- [**Application Registration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/app-registration)
- [Modify user and system variables in Visual Studio 2017 installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429709/modify-user-and-system-variables-in-visual-studio-2017-installer/52432169#52432169)
- ["Register" an .exe so you can run it from any command line in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822400/register-an-exe-so-you-can-run-it-from-any-command-line-in-windows)