# WiX environment component condition

Tags: wix, wix3.5

What is the best way to create environment variable only on first install of the application?
Using NOT Installed property condition did't work out for me tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Custom Action***: Are you using a custom action for this? There is no need to do so ([propaganda against custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779)). There are built-in features in MSI to update environment variables.

***WiX***: [Updating the Path variable using WiX is simple enough](https://github.com/robmen/gitsetup/blob/49583db00bc9e22ab3f0c0cb49b59b48fcbf6a10/src/Package/GitProduct.wxs#L15). That is a sample from the WiX makers themselves. You need to pay **very** close attention to how you configure that to see desired behavior. Test in all installation modes: `install`, `repair`, `self-repair`, `uninstall`, `patch`, `major upgrade`, `etc...`

Inlining sample from above link:

```
<Feature Id='Git'>
  <Component Directory='INSTALLFOLDER'>
    <RegistryValue Root='HKLM' Key='Software\Git' Name='InstallFolder' Value='[INSTALLFOLDER]' Type='string' />
    <Environment Id='UpdatePath' Name='PATH' Value='[dir6224ijVLx94XYG2KL6z4YR8qrrs]' Action='set' Part='last' System='yes' />
  </Component>
```

- The documentation for the [WiX Environment element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html).
- And here is the MSI SDK information for the actual [Environment Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/environment-table) in the final MSI (what is processed by Windows Installer during installation - the raw tables).

---

***Links***:

- [Modify user and system variables in Visual Studio 2017 installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429709/modify-user-and-system-variables-in-visual-studio-2017-installer/52432169#52432169)
- [Is it possible to register environment variables in Setup Wizard project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560234/is-it-possible-to-register-environment-variables-in-setup-wizard-project/21390793#21390793)
- [Wix Installer Going to Wrong Path on Command Line with Admin Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350871/wix-installer-going-to-wrong-path-on-command-line-with-admin-privilege)